# How to implement horizontal scrollview inside UIPageviewController

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uipageviewcontroller, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have a horizontal scroll view inside a UIPageViewController.
When i scroll horizontal view, UIPageViewControllerDataSource method viewControllerAfter called.

How to disable UIPageViewController scrolling, When horizontal scrollview contentSize greater than UIPageViewController contentSize.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable `UIPageViewController` by setting `nil` to it `delegate`, like `self.pageController.delegate = nil`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I need to disable only when my horizontal scroll view content size is greater than pageviewcontroller content size.